# where is the php folder located in macosx?

Tags: php, mac-osx, directory

I'm needing to modify my php config on my mac but for the life of me I can't find the files!

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`locate php.ini` or `updatedb && locate php.ini` if that fails (the updatedb will take a while). Apologies if these commands are not available on Mac OSX.

Comment: thanks for that! found it but in a strange place

/private/etc/php.ini.default - a lot different from in windows